# postgresql like in an array of jsonb

Tags: database, postgresql

[image]

I have a field datas as an array of json
when i query the field value with th exact value i have a result:

```
SELECT * FROM public.translations  WHERE datas::jsonb @> '[{"Value": "Autorisatie"}]'
```

[image]

My need is to query the value with a "like" not the exact value that's mean when i do

```
  SELECT * FROM public.translations  WHERE datas::jsonb @> '[{"Value": "%orisa%"}]'
```

i have the same result , how can i do it please?

Here a sample of my case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=07dc090f32b6f5f7a72e427bf920e888

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JSONB manipulation functions to decompose the object into individual records, and use `LIKE` afterwards:

```
SELECT key, value FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(datas) as data FROM public.translations) e, 
  jsonb_each_text(data) 
WHERE value LIKE '%orisa%';
```

Answer (score 0):

i do it like this,

```
SELECT * FROM public.translations  WHERE datas::jsonb::text like '%orisa%'
```

i don't know if it's a best solution or no.